# how to write an image file with orientation data as3

Tags: image, actionscript-3, file, air, orientation

i am writing  jpeg to file in air for android with as-3 
however, when i load the saved file from the image gallery it's orientation is wrong, or upside down or laying on the side. 
is there a way to write some kind of data in file so that the android will know if this image is portrait or landscape ?
how can i define the saved file if the image is landscape or portrait?

this is my code for writing the file

```
ImageSaverBMD.draw(ImageHolder);
var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(100);
var jpgBytes:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(ImageSaverBMD);
var myFile:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("Test Folder/test500.jpg");
var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
fs.open(myFile, FileMode.WRITE);
fs.writeBytes(jpgBytes);
fs.close();
```

Comment: Here's an EXIF manipulation library: https://github.com/bashi/exif-as3 It might be what you need.

Comment: I red a lot about it on the past 2 days but i didnt quite sure how to write it to the file, i know i can read it but not write does someone has a code example of how to do this. Thank you for your reply

Comment: when/how are the jpegs being created? eg from camera?